# Raw Expression in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

My sql code is :

```
Select * from table where cond(condition)1 and con2 ...... and(conX or conY).
```

How can i write it with raw expression. I don't know the keywork to solve this.

Update: My code is :

```
//$builder->to sql =   Select * from table where cond(condition)1 and con2 ...... ;
    if(something != true) $builder->whereRaw(conX);  
else $builder->whereRaw((conX or ConY));
    //$builder->to sql =   Select * from table where cond(condition)1 and con2 ...... and (conX or conY);
```

OK, it work, but i need to write conX 2 times, though it too long. So now i want to contract it.

```
//$builder->to sql =   Select * from table where cond(condition)1 and con2 ...... and conX;
if(something = true) $builder->raw or do something;   (@)
//$builder->to sql =   Select * from table where cond(condition)1 and con2 ...... and (conX or conY);
```

The question is that: What i should do in the (@) line to make the result as i expected

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (something == true) {
    $result = DB::table('table')
        ->selectRaw('*')
        ->where(condition1)
        ->where(condition2)
        ->get();
}
```

Or:

```
if (something == true) {
    $result = DB::table('table')
        ->select(DB::raw(YOUR SQL STATEMENT))
        ->get();
}
```

Further read:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: So you answered your own question? :D

Comment: the two 'conX' are not redundant, otherwise you would be forced to write more than one if-statement

Comment: i want to find out is there a way that i can write conX 1 time or not? i have not answered my question

Comment: i think no. because they are basically two different queries.